# I'm trying to insert a chart from a website into my google sheets document

Tags: xml, google-sheets, charts, import

I'm trying to create a google sheets document that displays certain market sentiments.
to do that I'd like to import this chart:
https://alternative.me/crypto/fear-and-greed-index.png

from this website
https://alternative.me/crypto/fear-and-greed-index/

I've tried =importXML however I keep getting invalids.

thanks for the help

Comment: Hi there @LochieCrear! If you want to update the picture as it changes, you should use a programmatic approach to refresh it in your desired timeframe. This could be easily done with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), would that approach be a valid one in your scenario?